# Instance member Goals cannot be used on type "ViewController" SWIFT XCODE

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hey I'm trying to Categorised or basically manually list stats in a way where i can give the program conditions to find exactly what I'm looking for so like if i was looking for how many goals where scored in the first 0 to 45 (first half) of a game that Barcelona was playing in on a specific day i could. Say in code find me all the games that were played on this date and where two or more goals were score in the first 0 to 45 minutes. As I'm not sure if i did it right but i tried to give the strings a number/Int value to represent the minute the goal was score in the game. And i also did the same with the date for the game. But the problem is there's an error at (don't Mind The spelling error lol "Barcelona")

```
 let BarcelonavsRealMadrid1 = [Goals, Penaltys]
```

Instance member Goals cannot be used on type "ViewController"

also if theres a better way to do this please you can rewrite my code. Thanks

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

     let Games = [BarcelonavsRealMadrid1: 1/13/14]
     let SpainPrimeraDivision = [RealMadrid, Bareclonia]
     let RealMadrid = [BarcelonavsRealMadrid1: 1/12/14]
     let Bareclonia = [BarcelonavsRealMadrid1: 1/12/14]

     let BarcelonavsRealMadrid1 = [Goals, Penaltys]
     let Goals : [String : Int] = ["BarcelonaGoal":21,"RealMadridGoal":23]
     let Penaltys  : [String : Int] = ["RealMadridPenalty":21,"BarcelonaPenalty":23]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: use `let BarcelonavsRealMadrid1 = [Goals, Penaltys]` in viewDidLoad

Comment: Your code is hardly readable. Follow the Swift coding guidelines.

Comment: Ok when i put it in the ViewDid load it says "Use of local variable goals before its declaration?

Comment: What is **Bareclonia**? ;-) The recommended way is to declare all instance variables which rely on other instance variables only with the type and assign an initial value in a method or to use lazy initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are making references between class properties during initialization - this isn't permitted. One way around this is to set some of the things initially, then in viewDidLoad or in viewWillAppear set the dependencies, like this:

```
//-------All Games Ever played------------------------------------
var BarcelonavsRealMadrid1 = [[String : Int]]()  // if you want this globally
let Goals : [String : Int] = ["BarcelonaGoal":21,"RealMadridGoal":23]
let Penaltys  : [String : Int] = ["RealMadridPenalty":21,"BarcelonaPenalty":23]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    BarcelonavsRealMadrid1 = [Goals, Penaltys]
}
```

also there were few more problems suggested by @luk2302 in his answer

Comment: Awesome but for the other valuables up top that are relying on the variable below we just edited it says the same and "Instance Member cannot be used on type ViewController. So I'm guessing i just do the same                var Games = [[AnyObject : Int]]()    but then theres an error and i can't Replace AnyObject with a string because its referencing a valuable

Comment: ya you have to tell that variable is string or any other type ... you can use any types in array ... but in the end you have to tell compiler that this is string or int or whatever it is

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reference one instance variable in the default assignment of another one. The following is the simplified version of your problem:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let foo = 12
    let bar = foo
}
```

Normally you have to setup the variables in the `init` method. But since you have a `UIViewController` here, you have to do it in `viewDidLoad`. You therefore have to write

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var foo : Int!
    var bar : Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        foo = 12
        bar = foo
    }
}
```

Your code has a *few* more problems than that however:

- you are trying to access variables before they are declared all over the place
- what is `1/12/14` supposed to be? I guarantee you it is not a date
- stop starting variable names with upper case letters

What you have to do:

- rename all your variables
- change all you variables to `var` and assign value to them **in the correct order** inside `viewDidLoad`
- deal with the *date situation*

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var BarcelonavsRealMadrid1:[[String:Int]] { return [Goals, Penaltys] }
```